# ExtJS 4.2.3 column layout does not support collaps panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have created a column layout and need one of the columns to collapse on a button click.

I have created this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/jbh) to demonstrate my need.

I expected that the remaining column will occupy the rest of the available space. I was wrong!

Is there a work around?

Answer (score 0):

One way is that you could nest a border layout inside another border layout and use collapsible:true

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'NG',

    launch : function() {
        var me = this;

        me.createViewport();
    },            

    createViewport: function(){
        var me = this;

        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'border',
            items:[{
                xtype: 'panel',
                region: 'north',
                weight: 10,
                html:'<H1>Header</H1>'
            },{
                xtype: 'panel',
                region:'center',
                layout:'border',
                items:[{
                    xtype:'panel',
                    region: 'center',
                    html:'<p>Column 1</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, amet porta ac. Justo nec mauris, et velit, tempus vitae elit elit, ac aliquam, penatibus donec in. Auctor faucibus eros vehicula tellus class sed, et in lacus tempus laoreet mollis, amet justo nascetur urna sem sem. Tellus nullam etiam eros lacus conubia, amet non. Vel nullam eget, urna ac, et at, nonummy ut amet mauris ipsum odio maecenas. Molestie aenean, diam a turpis sed dolor mauris hac. Nam in tellus sodales eros, penatibus torquent sodales iaculis mauris condimentum id, pellentesque pellentesque vestibulum aliquam, turpis rutrum tincidunt</p>'
                },{
                    xtype:'panel',
                    region:'east',
                    bodyStyle:'background-color: yellow;',
                    html:'<p>Column 2</p>',
                    width: 200,
                    collapsible:true
                }]
            },{
                xtype: 'panel',
                region: 'west',
                html:'<h2>Navigation</h2>',
                weight: 10
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

This will give you collapsible toggle control and the resizing of the other regions will get handled for you.

Comment: NO GOOD, I need the column layout as I need the column height variation based on the items content. sorry...